# Generating a category that only contains new products

Tags: magento2

We want to make a category that contains only NEW products. Products should be handled as new as long as the creating date isn't older then 2 weeks.

How can we achieve this? Magento seems not to have any functionality that does so.

Answer (score 0):

For achieve this ting ,you need to follow below steps

- First, **you need to create a category from admin**.
- Then create a custom cronjob,follow [Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/running-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/)
- That cronjob class `Inchoo\CronExample\Cron\Example:execute()`. make product collection which will contain *all products which are older then 2 max weeks*.
- then assign that products to that category.

> namespace Inchoo\CronExample\Cron; class Example { protected $_logger;
>   protected $_productCollectionFactory ; protected $_date;
>
> public function __construct(
>       \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,     \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
>       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory
>   $productCollectionFactory,
>       array $data = []
>       ) {   $this->_date = $date;
>       $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
>         $this->_logger = $logger;   }
>
> public function execute()   { 
>             $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();       $now = (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();       $dateStart = date('Y-m-d' . '
>   00:00:00',strtotime("-14 days"));         $latestEnd = date('Y-m-d' . '
>   23:59:59', $now);         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at',
>   array('gteq' =>$dateStart));
>         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq' =>
>   $latestEnd));         $ids=$collection->getAllIds();      $Idswihtindex=[];
>         foreach($ids as $id){           $Idswihtindex[$id]=0;       }
>             $category = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load('Your_CATEGORY_ID');
>         $category->setPostedProducts($Idswihtindex);        $category->save();  }
>   }

Comment: This answer is for Magento1. The question is for Magento 2.

Comment: Please check answer properly.answer is dor  magentow

Comment: As far as I know Mage::getModel is not supported nor executed by Mage2, or am I wrong here? Lookes so mixed. _objectManager is common to use for Mage2, but Mage::getModel('core/date') isn't. Will try your answer and give feedback!

Comment: Sorry for such as mistake...  I will edit this answer